# Pipe more doesn't seem to be working in Powershell v4.0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a command that displays several screens of text and I'm trying to use the `more` command, but it doesn't seem to be working.

When I try to use a command like this:

```
Get-Help Get-Alias -full | more
```

I get an error that says this:

```
more.com : The term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:14 char:14
+     $input | more.com
+              ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (more.com:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why?

Comment: I would say that you have a path or corrupt install issue. Worked fine for me.

Comment: What do you get by this command `gcm more -All`? I am getting the function `more` and the application `more.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that powershell.exe was not in the path.